# Does this property hold for these type of functions?

Tags: probability-theory

Assume that $X(t,\omega)$ is a stochastic process such that $\omega$. And we have that $E[\int_0^T X^2dt]<\infty$. Is then the r.v. $\int_0^TXdt$ in $L^2(P)$?

This looks a lot like what happens when the Ito Integral is constructed. We hvae that if $E[\int_0^T X^2dt]<\infty$ then  $\int_0^TXdB_s$ is in  $L^2(P)$.

But I can not replicate the proof, because the proof int he Ito case uses independent increments to get the Ito-isometry. But does it hold also when you generate with respect to dt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ito's Isometry:
$$||I\circ X||^{2}_{L^{2}(\mathbb{\Omega})}=\mathbb{E}\left(\int_{0}^{T}X_{t}\;dW_{t}\right)^{2}=\mathbb{E}\int_{0}^{T}X_{t}^{2}\;dt=||X||^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)\times L^{2}([0,T])}$$

Your question, however, is whether
$$||L\circ X||^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)}=\mathbb{E}\left(\int_{0}^{T}X_{t}\;dt\right)^{2}<\infty$$
if
$$||X||^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)\times L^{2}([0,T])}=\mathbb{E}\int_{0}^{T}X_{t}^{2}\;dt<\infty.$$
To see that this is the case, simply estimate using Holder's inequality (with one of the factors $\equiv1$)
$$\int_{\Omega}\left(\int_{0}^{T}X_{t}\;dt\right)^{2}\;d\mathbb{P}(\omega)\leq\int_{\Omega}\left(\int_{0}^{T}\;dt\int_{0}^{T}X_{t}^{2}\;dt\right)\;d\mathbb{P}(\omega)=T||X||_{L^{2}(\Omega)\times L^{2}([0,T])}^{2}<\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any stochastic analysis, just the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
\mathsf E\bigg(\int_0^T X_t dt\bigg)^2 \le \mathsf E\bigg[\int_0^T dt \int_0^T X_t^2 dt\bigg] = T\int_0^T  \mathsf E\big[X_t^2 dt\big]<\infty.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!